# No code was generated error on importing WCF to .netcore projects

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-core, wsdl

I have an issue with one of my old working WCF services which are working on normal & standard .net projects but the same project doesn't generate in **.net core 2.2**.

When I try to generate the code I got this error:

> Importing web service metadata ... Number of service endpoints found:
>   1 Scaffolding service reference code ... Warning:Warning: Reference
>   cannot be loaded: 'System.IO.Compression.Brotli', Could not load file
>   or assembly 'System.IO.Compression.Brotli, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Warning:Warning: Reference cannot be loaded: 'System.Memory', Could
>   not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Warning:Warning: There was a validation error on a schema generated
>   during export:
>       Source: 
>       Line: 27 Column: 10    Validation Error: Type 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hrms.Service.Entity:EmployeeMainInfo'
>   is not declared. Warning:Warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType Detail:
>   An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
>   Error: The datatype
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Hrms.Service.Entity:EmployeeMainInfo'
>   is missing. XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IHrmsService']
>   Warning:Warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding Detail: There was an error
>   importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on. XPath
>   to wsdl:portType:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IHrmsService']
>   XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IHrmsService']
>   Warning:Warning: Cannot import wsdl:port Detail:  XPath to Error
>   Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='HrmsService']/wsdl:port[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IHrmsService']
>   Warning:Warning: No endpoints compatible with .Net Core apps were
>   found. Generating files... Error:Error: No code was generated. If you
>   were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata
>   documents did not contain any valid contracts or services, or because
>   all contracts/services were discovered to exist in --reference
>   assemblies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the
>   tool. Done.

I have tried to update the mentioned references as well, but no luck.

How Can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Payam,
Did you find a solution to this issue?
I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Glenner003 this was core bug had to change platform to .net standard